# Descriptive Complexity characterzation of BPP

Tags: descriptive-complexity, probabilistic-complexity, first-order-logic

We know of descriptive complexity characterizations of classes such as **P**, and **NP**, which use First Order logic, and operators. Does **BPP** have a characterization under descriptive complexity, too(any reference known?)?

Comment: See the fairly recent paper [Kord Eickmeyer, Martin Grohe: Randomisation and Derandomisation in Descriptive Complexity Theory. Logical Methods in Computer Science 7(3) (2011)](https://doi.org/10.2168/LMCS-7(3:14)2011). According to the paper: *"... probabilistic classes such as BPP have received very little attention in
descriptive complexity theory yet ..."*